# Authenticate microsoft outlook web(owa) using rest client/javascript.

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-2010, rest-client

Authenticate microsoft outlook web(owa) using rest client/javascript.

What are the parameters required to authenticate outlook owa from rest client. I have tried passing username,password for url(https:///owa/auth.owa). But unable to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the domain url to "https:///owa/auth/owaauth.dll"

HTTP Method: POST

## Required Headers:

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

## Required Form parameters:

username=\&password=&flags=1&forcedownlevel=0&trusted=0&isUtf8=1&destination=https:///owa

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMZCI.png)